# QStringList::split - split a long string with data into many different QString

Tags: c++, split, qstring

I have a long list of data that contains data as follows:

```
"floatingnumber1a:floatingnumber1b,floatingnumber2a:floatingnumber2b,floatingnumber3a:floatingnumber3b"
```

I have them as a QString. Now I want to split them in two different arrays - one that contains the floatingnumbera values and one with floatingnumber b.

How can I do this? Maybe first I split them at each "," create a List with QStrings and then split each of them at the ":" to have two seperated strings which I can convert to double?!

But I don't know how to manage this.

I tried `split()`:

```
QStringList parts1 = data.split(",");
```

but whats than?

Answer (score 2):

First split the string on comma, then split each sub-string on colon, then convert the sub-sub-strings into floating-point numbers and add to respective collection.

Comment: okay, that was my plan as well. but unfortunately I don't know how I can convert the QStringList to QString again to to the splitting a second time?!

Comment: @smaica You *have* read the [`QStringList` reference documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstringlist.html)? Just iterate over it like any other Qt container.